# record user voice and clear text file every 2 minutes

Tags: ios, swift, text-files, speech-recognition

I am new to swift and I'm working in project that record user sound ,and convert sound file into text file every two minutes. I use timer to repeat the step every 2 minutes.

the problem is that the recorder is disable for the second call. Also, the text file does not clear the content to be prepared to the next call.

here is the full code.

```
import UIKit
import Speech
import AVFoundation



class ViewController: UIViewController {
var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
var inString = ""
let fileName = "Test"
  var str=""
appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value: Float(44100.0)),
                      AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
                      AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(1)),
                      AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue))]
var  timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: directoryURL()!, settings: recordSettings)
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    } catch {

        print("error")
    }
    audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        requestSpeechAuth()
    } catch {}
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 120, target: self, selector: #selector (ViewController.stopAudio), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func stopAudio() {
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false)

        let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "ar_SA"))
        let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: audioRecorder.url)
        recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error: \(error)")
            } else {
                let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                       in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(self.fileName).appendingPathExtension("txt") {
                    do {
                        self.str=""
                        self.str = (result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)!
                        try self.str.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    do {
                        self.inString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    self.getIqama(fileN: self.inString,status: self.str)
                }
            }//end elsd

        } //end result

    } catch {} //end do for false
    // requestSpeechAuth()
}

func directoryURL() -> URL? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as URL
    let soundURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("AqimAlsalat.m4a")
    return soundURL
}






func getIqama(fileN : String, status:String)
{

    var st: String!
  st = "السلام عليكم ورحمة الله السلام عليكم ورحمة الله"

    let st1 : String!
    st1 = String (fileN)
    print(st1)
    if st1 == st {

        // audioEngine.stop()
        //speechRecognitionRequest?.endAudio()
        print(st1)
          print("JJalal")
    }
    else {
        print("Dalal")
        print(fileN)
    }
}

func requestSpeechAuth(){
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
        if authStatus == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
                self.audioRecorder.record()
            } catch {}
        }
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

any suggestion or idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to call `self.audioRecorder.record()` again after you stop the recording to convert the soundfile into text. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/1388252-record) say that calling `record()` will create or erase an audio file, so that should solve your problem.

However, you may encounter another problem where you miss a period of recording while you are transcribing the text. You could consider fixing that problem by switching back and forth between two recorders, or you could try to change the audio recorder's file location (or change the location of the previous file) before starting to record again.